# Set background images slider for website on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, background, slider

I have on my client's website an HTML embedded video background and it works fine on Desktop, but on mobile it doesn't because it needs to set some more parameters.

So I want to display a background slider of images when the website loaded on mobile.

Means I want to load for : Desktop = HTML video / Mobile-Tablet = slider.

The questions, is how I can add the slider and make it works , pleaase ??

P.s: the piece of code of HTML video

```
                    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" poster=""> 
                    <source src="videos/video-1.webm" type="video/webm"> 
                    <source src="videos/video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
                    <source src="videos/video-1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    <p>Your browser does not support the video element. Try this page in a modern browser!</p>   
                    </video>
```

CSS :

```
    #video_background { 
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -1000;
overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Best regards :)

Comment: Perhaps you want to set the [poster image](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp)?

Comment: No I want a slider of multiple images not just a static image !

Comment: There's no answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to load a different element in place of the video in mobile.

You could use @media queries, but you'd be loading both elements in the background on mobile.

```
#slider { display: none; } 
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #video-background { display: none; }
  #slider { display:block; }
}
```

This will work entirely off of screen size. To target specific devices more accurately, [look here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Alternatively, you can serve the video for desktop-only on the server side and not use as much bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for the response , I'll try your tips